# how to check Excel Server is present or not?

Tags: excel

I want to check the presence of ExcelServer on a  legacy system.

There are EXCEL spreadsheets present on this system.Also one can open, edit and save EXCEL sheets.
But when I check the presence ExcelServer on the C:/ Program files...only 0 kb files are there under MS office(11)/ Excel.
Som can 0 kb files deal be ok for an Working Excel sheets?

Only EXCEL folder is there in the MS office.(0 kb/MS word etc are missing).
When I do a global search for EXCEL,  there were Excel11.pip( 11 kb ),but no EXCEL server.

What are these Excel11.pip files? 
How to find EXCEL server is present or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as Excel Server, AFAIK. The Excel application, however, can be tested for by trying to create the COM object ExcelApplication. A quick search of either SO or Google should find you some code for whatever language you're working with - a typical means of doing so is by using CreateCOMObject().

Answer (score 1):

Using the registry?

[EDIT]

by checking the presence of the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office in the windows registry

Comment: "registry"...can you provide some details please?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, and try to obtain an instance of Excel like
var excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application().

Comment: This might be a good answer, if vas had mentioned what language he was working in. It wouldn't be good, for example, if vas was working in C or VB < VB.NET.

Comment: Agreed, regarding the language. This got me reading the question again, and it is confusing. If "one can open, edit and save EXCEL sheets", then Excel must be on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

.pip files are [Preference file used by Microsoft Office programs to store "Personalized Menus and Toolbars" settings](http://fileinfo.com/extension/pip), in this case for version 11, ie Excel 2003.